# Select columns using select_ in dplyr when column names have brackets

Tags: r, dplyr

In my data frame, the column names have brackets. I want to use the function `select_` to pick up columns I need.

However, I got an error message

```
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'A.B.V1' not found
```

How could I solve this problem?

This is a minimumal example to reproduce my problem.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- data_frame(`A.B.V1:7(1)` = seq(1, 10), B = seq(1, 10))
# Can select one column
a %>% select(`A.B.V1:7(1)`)
# Cannot select columns
col <- c('A.B.V1:7(1)', 'B')
a %>% select_(.dots = col)
```

Comment: As of [dplyr 0.7.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases), the underscore versions of main verbs like `select_` are no longer needed since dplyr now takes a tidyeval approach to non-standard evaluation. `a %>% select(col)` will work fine on its own.

Comment: The underscore versions are also officially deprecated and might be removed in some future release, so solutions that use the new behaviour will probably be most useful.

Comment: alternatively, you can use `dplyr::rename()` to **rename your column rows** so that they don't contain brackets, and avoid the backticks, backquotes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backquotes, eg:

```
col <- c('`A.B.V1:7(1)`', 'B')
a %>% select_(.dots = col)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
`A.B.V1:7(1)`     B
<int> <int>
1             1     1
2             2     2
3             3     3
4             4     4
5             5     5
6             6     6
7             7     7
8             8     8
9             9     9
10            10    10
```